# Problem Booting

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I have two hard drives 1TB and 250GB. I installed windows on the 1TB drive and I installed ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on 250GB drive. My problem is it is not asking which OS to boot. Is there any thing except changing hard disk priority every time I wants to boot OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this problem by changing the hardDisk priority
change ubuntu installed hard disk(250gb) has to boot first in boot menu